# Is there an algorithm to combine audio from multiple microphones to improve audio quality?

Tags: algorithm, audio

Consider a situation where you have multiple microphones, each capable of transmitting the audio they pick up over a wifi network (meaning that the audio can be time delayed by several milliseconds or more).

Is there an algorithm that can combine the audio from multiple microphones to produce a higher quality audio recording, detecting and correcting for any time delay?

Comment: looking after a similar task, I found the related question https://superuser.com/questions/40931/combine-multiple-audio-files-into-a-single-higher-quality-audio-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the detection/correction of time delay, you might want to look for ["feature extraction"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=audio%20feature%20extraction&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=gn1dUo3AKIXS9QSx2YDQBg&ved=0CCwQgQMwAA). It determines key points in the audio to match up.

This works best if all the microphones are hearing (roughly) the same thing, though. For a studio-type environment, where each mic is directional and aimed at a different instrument, it may have a very hard time identifying common features.

---

I'm unsure of what "higher quality" means to you, though. I assume you mean the least amount of noise. If that's the case, you might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3882611/752320), which is about noise detection. You can calculate the signal/noise ratio of each input and weight them as you see fit when combining.

There are other ways to reduce noise as well. You could simply run one of many [noise reduction](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=audio%20noise%20reduction&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0,10&as_vis=1) techniques on each input, or on the mixed output.

If you mean something else by "quality", then you might be headed into tougher areas. There is a reason professional mixers get paid, because computers aren't good at telling what sounds "better".

---

Of course, there may not be any need to reinvent the wheel at all. There are probably several open-source programs that do this kind of stuff. I'd think the [Audacity source](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/source) would have everything you want.

Comment: The application I have in mind is actually more like a conference call situation - where you have multiple people seated around a table, with multiple microphones.  Depending on the microphone and the speaker, the audio quality and volumes will differ, along with any audio displacement.  The idea would be to combine the audio from the various microphones to provide clear audio from the various people speaking.

Comment: Hmm. In that case I think the general idea is the same. You might not want to combine audio from all microphones, though. Compare the relative volume and signal/noise of each, and select the best. If none rise above your threshold, combine the best two. Maybe run noise reduction and automatic gain control on it once mixed. I don't think you're going to find a single "algorithm" for this, as it's a pretty broad subject.

Comment: Thanks, yes - I'm more hoping for some general pointers to ensure that I'm not overlooking anything before I attempt to come up with my own solution.